Different Datasets in One Machine learning Model
I have two different datasets with different number of features. I want to classify stress level and factor by using random forest model. My target variables are " low, Medium, High". Stress Factors are 5 factors in one dataset and 4 factors in the other dataset. When I get final results on each dataset, what can I do with these different results on each dataset in one model and what information can be shown?
I want to know that when I get final results on each dataset, what can I do other things with these different results on each dataset in one model and what information can be shown beside stress level and stress factor?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
